# Can't infer type F when returning a Future type

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm trying to write a function which would return a `Future`, so following [a tutorial from Tokio](https://tokio.rs/docs/going-deeper/returning/), I came up with this:

```
extern crate tokio;

use std::time::{Duration, Instant};
use tokio::prelude::*;
use tokio::timer::Interval;

fn run<F>() -> impl Future<Item = (), Error = F::Error>
where
    F: Future<Item = ()>,
{
    Interval::new(Instant::now(), Duration::from_millis(1000))
        .for_each(move |instant| {
            println!("fire; instant={:?}", instant);
            Ok(())
        })
        .map_err(|e| panic!("interval errored; err={:?}", e))
}

fn main() {
    tokio::run(run());
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=6430015544636e20c9b7380167181509)

I get this error:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:20:16
   |
20 |     tokio::run(run());
   |                ^^^ cannot infer type for `F`
```

I assume the error will go away once I specify the full return type, which I can't even figure out (my IDE gives me `<futures::MapErr<futures::stream::ForEach<tokio::timer::Interval, [closure@src/ir.rs:24:23: 38:14 self:_], std::result::Result<(), tokio::timer::Error>>, [closure@src/ir.rs:39:22: 39:65]>`)

1. How can I figure out the type? Any IDE tips or tricks? (I'm using Atom with ide-rust)
2. Can I somehow get away with just defining `impl Future<Item = (), Error = F::Error> where F: Future<Item = ()>`?

   I'm fine with defining the full type somewhere inside of `run` function, but to the outside of the function I'd like to expose `<Future<Item = (), Error = F::Error>>` or `<Future<Item = (), Error = io::Error>>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [`tokio::run`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1/tokio/runtime/fn.run.html)'s signature:

```
pub fn run<F>(future: F) 
where
    F: Future<Item = (), Error = ()> + Send + 'static,
```

The consumed future must have the associated `Error` type equal to `()`. This implies that you cannot be generic over the error.

This works:

```
fn run() -> impl Future<Item = (), Error = ()> {
    Interval::new(Instant::now(), Duration::from_millis(1000))
        .for_each(move |instant| {
            println!("fire; instant={:?}", instant);
            Ok(())
        })
        .map_err(|e| panic!("interval errored; err={:?}", e))
}

fn main() {
    tokio::run(run());
}
```